# Core Data one-to-many relationship save

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, relationship

Have a problem with relationships one-to-many.

How implement tables something like this.

I have a 3 lists of users,

1 - matched users,

2-all users,

3- selected users.

How i must link object to for example to **Matched_users** table? And after that download data from Core Data? 
I'm using NSFetchResultController in tableView, and I must link my fetch request to User table or to **Matched_users** table?

Core Data table

[image]

Comment: why do you have entities for all, matched and selected - how do you think they help you? what is the app actually going to do? how do you match / select?

Comment: app will be look like this:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/qcktpbvqd40lsds/KogwzsnQ-CM.jpg?dl=0
And I do a 3 request to server for getting all, matched and selected users.
How I must save them to database? Or maybe only add a extra parameter for matched and selected users?

Answer (score 1):

By looking at the schema, I am wondering it you can make two attributes `matched` and `selected` in the User table.You can get all users anyway.
Let the `Photos` entity as it is.
Let me know if you are looking for something else.